# Sun light and leaf color

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, sun

Wien's displacement law :

$\lambda_{peak}T=2.898\times 10^{-3}m\cdot K$

Temp of sun = 5000

so sun radiate green wave in max volume.

but atmosphere of earth refract sun light and blue wave is max  in earth surface.

so for leaf it is the best to absorb the max wave that reach them = blue  ==>  leafs with blue color are rare.

but why leaf did not absorb green color ?

Answer (score 0):

Plants are green because they reflect green light and absorb blue and red.

Also, blue light is *scattered* in the atmosphere.

Comment: Chlorophyll A absorbs energy from blue-violet and orange-red light, while chlorophyll B absorbs energy from green light.  Chlorophyll B just collects energy for chlorophyll A.